# Create a loop to process multiple files

Tags: python

I have written the code below but currently I need to retype the same conditions for each file and, as there are over 100 files, this is not ideal.

I couldn't come up with a way to implement this using a loop that will read all of these files and filter the values in MP out. Meanwhile, adding two new columns to each filter file as the written code below would be the only method I know so far.
I try to obtain a new combined data frame with all filter files with their conditions

Please suggest ways of implementing this using a loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

df1 = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Unmanned Cars\Unmanned Cars\2017040810_052.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Unmanned Cars\Unmanned Cars\2017040901_052.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Unmanned Cars\Unmanned Cars\2017040902_052.csv')

df1 =df1["MP"].unique()
df1=pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['MP'])
df1["Dates"] = "2017-04-08"
df1["Inspection"] = "10"
##
df2 =df2["MP"].unique()
df2=pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=['MP'])
df2["Dates"] = "2017-04-09"
df2["Inspection"] = "01"
##
df3 =df3["MP"].unique()
df3=pd.DataFrame(df3, columns=['MP'])
df3["Dates"] = "2017-04-09"
df3["Inspection"] = "02"
Final = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4],axis = 0, sort = False)
```

Comment: Do you know how to write loops in general? What specific issue do you have using loops for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this sample code will help you.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from os import path
import glob
import re

def process_file(file_path):
    result = None
    file_path = file_path.replace("\\","/")
    filename = path.basename(file_path)
    regex = re.compile("^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})")
    match = regex.match(filename)
    if match:
        date = "%s-%s-%s" % (match[1] , match[2] , match[3])
        inspection = match[4]

        df1 = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        df1 =df1["MP"].unique()
        df1=pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['MP'])
        df1["Dates"] = date
        df1["Inspection"] = inspection
        result = df1
    return result


def main():
#    files_list = [
#        r'E:\Unmanned Cars\Unmanned Cars\2017040810_052.csv',
#        r'E:\Unmanned Cars\Unmanned Cars\2017040901_052.csv',
#        r'E:\Unmanned Cars\Unmanned Cars\2017040902_052.csv'
#    ]
    directory = 'E:\\Unmanned Cars\\Unmanned Cars\\'
    files_list =  [f for f in glob.glob(directory + "*_052.csv")]

    result_list = [ process_file(filename) for filename in files_list ]

    Final = pd.concat(result_list, axis = 0, sort = False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've created a **process_file** function for processing each file. 
There is used a [regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) for extracting data from filename. Also, the glob module was used for reading the files from a directory with pattern matching and expansion.

Comment: When I run the output for the Final, It said the Final is not defined. Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've basically modified your code so it can address the loops and process all files. I've tested with a sample CSV (different dataset than yours, and minimal adapting chances) and it worked for me. Did you install the dependencies for this to work? (pandas, matplotlib, numpy, scipy)

Comment: I installed all of the dependencies, but It is still not working. What is your email? I will send files to you.

Comment: It seems to be out of the scope of the original question, as the loop did the job. Now, how are you doing `run the output for the Final`?

Comment: "Please suggest ways of implementing this using a loop" -- I gave a code sample to you as a solution for the burden of processing those files with a loop. It should also be useful for learning the basic syntax of python. The last Final keyword is a variable that has no use in your code, therefore not in mine. How you use it beyond this, is out of this scope IMHO. Sorry, I couldn't be more helpful.